# Formula assistance continued

Tags: microsoft-excel

Thank you for your help on my first problem. Now for the 2nd part.

OK, Now In my spreadsheet, I need to score a multipart question that already has been scored, but I need to break it down and score it again.

Example(If F2 which is a survey question and the agent can score a 5,4,3,2 or 1.) I need to throw out the 3,2,1 and concentrate on the 5,4 and score that. 5 or 4 =5 points. I know that if I write =if(f2=5,5,0) but how do I include the 4?

Comment: You forgot to Accept the solution on your previous question.

Comment: Don't forget to mark solution as answered by clicking the check mark next to the Answer.

Comment: @ejbytes How do I accept it?

Comment: There is a faint check mark near the Zero on my answer. Simply click on it and it will turn green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to ask "OR?"

> I know that if I write =if(f2=5,5,0) but how do I include the 4?

=if(**OR(f2=5, f2=4)**,5,0)

Comment: Thank you very much, I am appreciative for your help, I have just recently developed a skill in data analytics. This will help me create the combined pivot tables I need for the contest.

Comment: @MatthewDouglas My pleasure, and welcome again to Superuser!